# How to export SQLite db to Tally.ERP format in Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I need to export my SQLite db to `Tally.ERP` format. I have already exported my db to Excel. I have tried to find a guide explaining how to convert it to tally format, but found nothing.

How can I export my SQLite db to `Tally.ERP` format in Android?

Comment: What is extension of tally format?

Comment: I think ,Tally.ERP default file extension associations

1.500  2.tcp

Answer (score 0):

You must convert the SQLite data into Tally XML format.

To understand the Tally XML format, the steps are given underneath:

1. Start Tally and manually enter a voucher (ex: Sales)
2. Export it in XML format using Gateway of Tally >> Display >> Daybook >> Alt+E
3. This generates a file named Daybook.xml which contains Tally XML tags for that Voucher.